# dividing transparent objects into individual shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator How do I divide two overlapping shapes into individual parts so the overlap area is a shape and the non overlap areas are two shapes.  So I end up with three shapes that can each stand alone and be colored individually?

Comment: also if you use transpsrent shapes then transparency flattener does this

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of possibilities:

1. Open the `Pathfinder` palette (`Window > Pathfinder` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control / Option</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) and use the `Divide` option—the first icon on the second line. This makes the three shapes into a group. Ungroup them and you can edit them.
2. Select both shapes, choose the `Shape builder` tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and click each of the three shapes once. Then they'll be separate and can be edited as such.

Answer (score 0):

Select the object and choose `Object > Flatten Transparency...`